# JSON_QUOTE() or JSON_ARRAY() equivalent in old version of MYSQL/Mariadb?

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

I am working with an old version of MariaDB (10.0.38-MariaDB) and it does not support any JSON function.

I have a very complicated script that reads each row as a JSON at step 1. I tried to replicate json_array with concat_ws and used replace function to replace **["]** with **[\"]** .
but there are several escape characters like the break line.

I was wondering is there any equivalent to json_quote() for older versions?

my first code looks something like this but it's not good enough.

```
        concat('[', concat_ws(',', 
    ifnull(concat('"', replace(replace(`mobile`, '\\', '\\\\') , '"', '\"'), '"'), 'null'), 
    ifnull(concat('"', replace(replace(`phone`, '\\', '\\\\') , '"', '\"'), '"'), 'null'), 
    ifnull(concat('"', replace(replace(`address`, '\\', '\\\\') , '"', '\"'), '"'), 'null'), 
    ifnull(concat('"', replace(replace(`coordinate`, '\\', '\\\\') , '"', '\"'), '"'), 'null'),
    ifnull(concat('"', replace(replace(`national_code`, '\\', '\\\\') , '"', '\"'), '"'), 'null')) , ']') as json
```

Comment: JSON is fairly simple, but not that simple. Consider: Newline characters, etc.

Comment: If you're using JSON extensively, which is great, upgrade your MySQL/MariaDB to take full advantage of it. You won't regret it. Rolling your own janky JSON functions is how you introduce subtle, but devastating bugs that only manifest years down the road.

Comment: i would love to do that but I only have a read access to that server and no power to change anything

Comment: Influencing those that can change to make the system better is an important part of the role of a technical professional.

Comment: You don't. If the platform doesn't support json, don't use json. You're not going to succeed in rolling your own json library in SQL. Why does the data need formatting as json? Why can't that be done externally to the database? This appears to be an [xyproblem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: it's very complicated but in short, I am reading from +100 tables with different schema and doing some ETL. to make all the tables look like each other I am reducing them to 2 columns 
id and a JSON that contains the rest of the columns. this way I can follow my pipeline till the last step where I open the JSON again.

Comment: That's misuse of your Relational Database. Even if you had json functions available, you shouldn't collapse a relational schema into a json string. Especially if the purpose is simply to make it easier to manually track your pipeline. I strongly recommend against your current approach.

Comment: ok, maybe I should be more clear.
I am using SSIS to ETL data to sql_server. in SSIS dataflow table schema is not dynamic but I want to use a single package for all tables. so I need to have the same schema for all tables. this is how I managed to fix that issue and my SSIS package has been working for more than 3 years now with a  lot of features and bug fixes so I don't want to develop a new method from the ground up like python or something else only for this small database.

Comment: I'll point out that all versions of both MySQL and MariaDB that are old enough to lack JSON functions are past their end-of-life ([MariaDB 10.0 ended in March 2019](https://endoflife.date/mariadb)). You really ought to upgrade to a version that is supported. Once you do, you'll be using a version that has JSON functions.

Comment: If you're using Python, why not use Python to do the JSON transformation for you? It has feature complete libraries for that.

Comment: I am not using Python. 
if I can't find a solution I have to build a pipeline from the ground up using python.

Comment: Do you collect antiques? MariaDB 10.0 reached end of life in 2019.